# How print entire row after searching a value using pandas and scv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hello I have had some trouble with my projecting I'm trying to make someting where you can search a value and it returns an the row that value was in. I've only been able to do it with the atomic number because they're ordered. I was planning to use classes but I don't think I'll actually need it (that's what import element is for)

Here's my code:

```
from __init__ import element
import csv
import pandas
import elements

while True:
    # Search Options
    print("Search options: ")
    print("Search by Atomic Symbol")
    print("Search by Atomic Number")
    print("Search by Atomic Weight")
    print("Search by English Name")
    print("Search by Dutch Name")

    searchOption = input().lower()

    if searchOption == "atomic number":
        # Search by atomic number
        atNum = int(input("Atomic number: "))

        df = pandas.read_csv("elements.csv", index_col="atNum")

        print(f"Atomic Symbol: {df.iloc[atNum - 1].atSym}")
        print(f"Atomic Weight: {df.iloc[atNum - 1].atWeight}")
        print(f"English Name:  {df.iloc[atNum - 1].ENname}")
        print(f"Dutch Name:    {df.iloc[atNum - 1].NLname}")
        
        print("=====================================")
```

Here's a **sample** of my CSV file

```
atSym,atNum,atWeight,ENname,NLname
H,1,1.008,hydrogen,waterstof
He,2,4.0026,helium,helium
Li,3,6.94,lithium,lithium
Be,4,9.0122,beryllium,beryllium
B,5,10.81,boron,boor
C,6,12.011,carbon,koolstof
N,7,14.007,nitrogen,stikstof
O,8,15.999,oxigen,zuurstof
F,9,18.998,fluorine,fluor
Ne,10,20.180,neon,neon
Na,11,22.990,sodium,natrium
Mg,12,24.305,magnesium,magnesium
Al,13,26.982,aluminium,aluminium
Si,14,28.085,silicon,silicium
P,15,30.974,phosphorus,fosfor
S,16,32.06,sulfur,zwavel
Cl,17,35.45,chlorine,chloor
Ar,18,39.948,argon,argon
K,19,39.098,potassium,kalium
Ca,20,40.078,calcium,calcium
Sc,21,44.956,scandium,scandium
Ti,22,47.867,titanium,titanium
V,23,50.942,vanadium,vanadium
Cr,24,51.996,chromium,chroom
Mn,25,54.938,manganese,mangaan
Fe,26,55.845,iron,ijzer
Co,27,58.933,cobalt,kobalt
Ni,28,58.693,nickel,nikkel
Cu,29,63.546,copper,koper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do so you can search for different options:

```
# df is not changing, so no need to read it on every iteration
df = pandas.read_csv("elements.csv")

# mapping between search options and columns in the DataFrame
d = {
    'atomic symbol': 'atSym',
    'atomic number': 'atNum',
    'atomic weight': 'atWeight',
    'english name': 'ENname',
    'dutch name': 'NLname',
}

while True:
    # Search Options
    print("Search options: ")
    print("Search by Atomic Symbol")
    print("Search by Atomic Number")
    print("Search by Atomic Weight")
    print("Search by English Name")
    print("Search by Dutch Name")

    # get search option and select the right column to search on
    # we're converting the column to lowercase strings, so that
    # we can conveniently find it later
    searchOption = input().lower()
    df_ix = df[d[searchOption]].astype(str).str.lower()
    
    # get value to search for, convert to lowercase and find row
    searchValue = input().lower()
    row = df[df_ix==searchValue]
    
    # rename columns to human-readable based on our mapping and print
    print("=====================================")
    print(row.rename(columns={v: k for k, v in d.items()}))
    print("=====================================")
```

Example output:

```
Search options: 
Search by Atomic Symbol
Search by Atomic Number
Search by Atomic Weight
Search by English Name
Search by Dutch Name
 english name
 helium
=====================================
  atomic symbol  atomic number  atomic weight english name dutch name
1  He             2             4.0            helium       helium   
=====================================
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the row number?

Comment: Yes, you can do `print(row.rename(...).to_string(index=False))`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, in Windows the path needed to be `elementify/elementsList.csv` and on Mac it was fine with `elementsList.csv`I've released it now https://github.com/shibaismyname/elementify if you want to check it out, im still working on it though.